# How to install ubuntu 18.04 on my existing ubuntu 17.04 LTS with live DVD or USB

Tags: system-installation

I am now use ubuntu 17.04. I gonna interested to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my computer . But i am worry about my hard disk files . How to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS replaced with 17.04 LTS and safe my hard disk files exclude operating system files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the way you installed ubuntu 17.04, (by going to boot options).

It will detect the existing files, and will prompt if you want a clean install or preserve the existing files.